# Issue from an old Opencart version of my website

Tags: opencart

My old website was on Opencart, the new one is now a custom website - same domain.

The issue is that I still see index.php URLs in google's index (search console keeps finding such URLs too). The website was migrated about a year ago.

1/3 of the indexed URLs on google are with index.php parameters. They all redirect to either the home page or a relevant one.

How do I find where is the issue generating these URLs?

Would very much appreciate your help guys!

Comment: please send me your website url please ? i see it and response to you. and what is actual issue?  i dont understand what you say.

Answer (score 0):

you can find those url using google search console, google analytics (traffic source)

and some google search tips like

inurl:yoursiteoldurl and site:yourdomainname